# Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, mindsdb

I am trying to install the Python library called `mindsdb` with *pip*, but I got an error like this:

```
Collecting mindsdb
  Using cached MindsDB-23.6.1.1.tar.gz (6.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v9b2a_j0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v9b2a_j0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v9b2a_j0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\Neelesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-v9b2a_j0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 87, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 41, in define_deps
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements\\requirements.txt'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip
```

I have also tried the following commands:

```
pip install mindsdb
pip install mindsdb --pre
pip install --upgrade pip
```

None of them have worked for me.

Comment: The packaging of the version [23.6.1.1](https://inspector.pypi.io/project/mindsdb/23.6.1.1/packages/0b/1b/bf1cfe1d2e859b69581457694efa163acd8171a9590093c33575e3fda118/MindsDB-23.6.1.1.tar.gz/) of that library seems to have issues. There is no `requirements/requirements.txt` file in the source distribution. The latest version does not seem that have this issue. -- Is there a reason why this specific version gets selected? You should try later version if posisble.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

First, install this, then it might work.