# Error in Mindsdb installation in Ubuntu using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, pip, mindsdb

```
Collecting mindsdb
  Using cached MindsDB-23.6.1.1.tar.gz (6.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/activelap13/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/activelap13/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/activelap13/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-m_ejci5d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-m_ejci5d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-m_ejci5d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-m_ejci5d/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 87, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 41, in define_deps
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements/requirements.txt'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This error originates from a `subprocess`, and is likely not a problem with `pip`.

I am trying to install **Mindsdb** in ubuntu using python pip but i am getting above error message . its related to some python dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526161/getting-requirements-to-build-wheel-did-not-run-successfully-exit-code-1-sub#comment134930166_76526161 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip+mindsdb

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with that version of mindsdb. Please install the latest one  MindsDB 23.7.2.0 `pip install mindsdb==23.7.2.0`

Comment: yeah I tried this also . still i am having same issue

Comment: Impossible this should work. Maybe you don't have latest pip or you are using un-supported python version?

Comment: i had tried with all possibility but still was getting above error